# Xml namespaces https compliance

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, https

We are in the process of making our MVC4 site https compliant.

In our global resource files we have xmlns's declared like

```
<xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

To make our site https compliant should these be declared as such ?

```
<xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

We had issues being unable to display svg files when we tried to use

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Icon" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 46.9 46.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 46.9 46.8;" xml:space="preserve">
```

instead of

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 46.9 46.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 46.9 46.8;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace name for xsd is always `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` and for svg it is always `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`. It cannot be changed. This has nothing to with making any site "https compliant".

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707609/xml-namespace-uri-with-https) answer.

> The URI is the namespace name, which identifies the namespace.
>
> While, in case of some URI schemes (like http, https, ftp etc.), it
>   would be possible to provide the schema (or other related
>   information), this is "not a goal":