# What should be the value of xmlns attribute for urlset tag in the sitemap?

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

My sitemap looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/page1.html</loc> 
   </url>
</urlset>
```

In the most examples in the internet `urlset` tag has a `xmlns` attribute with this value `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`. My question is, what that value comes from?

What exactly should it be?

1. The path of where my website sitemap file is located?
2. Literally `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) defines the XML schema which has the namespace `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`.

By using

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

you convey that the `urlset` element (and its descendants, unless they have a different namespace) should be interpreted according to this Sitemap protocol.

Namespaces help to avoid name collisions. There is no central authority that controls which element names can be used in XML, so any other XML schema may specify an element named `urlset`, too. Namespaces also allow you to mix elements from different XML schemas, e.g., for [extending the Sitemaps protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending).

tl;dr: You have to provide ([exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761004/1591669)!) this namespace value, otherwise it wouldn’t be a sitemap as defined by the Sitemap Protocol.

Comment: Ok I understood some notes about namespaces and `xmlns` attribute. But still I'm not sure about the value of `xmlns` for my own website. Should it be literally `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ: Yes, as the last sentence of my answer says :) If you want to have a sitemap compliant to the Sitemaps Protocol (sitemaps.org), you have to use this namespace. If you use a different namespace, your XML document is not a Sitemaps Protocol sitemap, but something else (depending on the namespace you use).

Answer (score 0):

I readed many blogs and also read the sitemap protocol at schema.org but the issue was not resolved but after week of reasearching this i found out that

This type of sitemap is for old xhtml sites

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And this version is for new html sites as per many cms like wordpress builds i may be wrong

```
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```